# Como separar el texto de otro

Tags: javascript

***Si creo un texto de la siguiente forma:***

```js
function urlify(text) {
    var urlRegex =/(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?  =~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
    return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
    });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){
var m = document.getElementById("m");
var t = prompt('Ingresa texto','Texto:');
var p = "";
var nombre = prompt('nombre de usuario','');
var testd = urlify(t);
if(testd.indexOf('href="') != -1) {
p = document.createElement("A")
}
else {
p = document.createElement("P")
}
var texto = document.createTextNode(nombre + ": " + testd);
p.style.color = "white";
p.appendChild(texto);
m.appendChild(p);
});
```

```css
#m {width:300px:height:200px;background-color:rgba(21,21,21,0.75)}
```

```html
<div id="m">



</div>
```

***Explico:***

Creo el controlador `addEventListener`, para ejecutar cuando todo los elementos esten cargados, defino `m` que es el div, defino `t` que es el texto que ingresara, defino `p` que sera un `createElement`, segun un `IF`, **este** `if` sera `true` segun una `funcion` que ***verifica si es un link de tipo*** *http://link.com*, si se verifica *true*, **crea un elemento A**, **sino uno P**, luego creo el texto con `createTextNode` y en los argumentos, le paso el **nombre** , un **separador** `": "` y el **texto**, de manera que quedaria como:

> Usuario: mensaje

***El problema es que como puedo hacer para que el nombre aparezca de OTRO COLOR que el del mensaje, y además al intentar CREAR el elemento A, no aparece como LINK***

Answer (score 1):

Veo algunos problemas:

1. Con la función urlify, si es una url la transformas a una cadena del tipo `<a href="url">url</a>`. Y al crear un nodo de texto con `createTextNode`, esa cadena no se transformará a un enlace, sino que se mantendrá como texto literal. Podría interpretarse como elemento (y verse el enlace) si lo añadieras con `innerHTML` al elemento en lugar de creando un nodo de texto.

   Solución: Añade el texto como nodo de texto sólo si no es un enlace, y usa `innerHTML` sólo si es una URL válida y ha sido procesado como tal (ojo: este método no es el mejor porque puede sufrir ataques de XSS, sería mejor que cambiaras urlify para que devolviera `true`/`false` y crear un enlace adecuadamente).
2. Incluso si la url se devolviera como elemento `a`, se crearía un `a` al que no le estás asignando ningún `href` por lo que no se mostraría como enlace. Y además, el HTML generado sería inválido, porque entonces tendrías un `a` dentro de otro `a` (en la forma `<a>usuario <a>url</a></a>`) y el resultado podría no ser el esperado.

   Solución: No hace falta que crees un elemento `a` si es una URL, ya has creado el elemento `a` si es un enlace en urlify. Crea siempre un `p`.
3. Para que el nombre de usuario se muestre con otro color, vas a tener que envolverlo en una etiqueta propia. Esto es porque en CSS no hay (al menos de momento) un selector para la primera palabra de la frase.

   Solución: crea un elemento `span` y envuelve el nombre del usuario con él. Con CSS dale estilos a ese span para que se vea de diferente manera.

Entonces los cambios a hacer serían:

```js
function urlify(text) {
  var urlRegex = /(\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?  =~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
  return text.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var m = document.getElementById("m");
  var t = prompt('Ingresa texto', 'Texto:');
  var p = "";
  var nombre = prompt('nombre de usuario', '');
  var testd = urlify(t);
  p = document.createElement("P")
  
  // creamos y rellenamos un span para el nombre del usuario
  var nombre_tag = document.createElement("span");
  var nombre_txt = document.createTextNode(nombre);
  nombre_tag.className = "nombre-usuario";
  nombre_tag.appendChild(nombre_txt);
  p.appendChild(nombre_tag);
  
  // dependiendo del valor devuelto por urlify creamos un enlace o no
  if (testd.indexOf('<a href="') != 0) {
    var texto = document.createTextNode(": " + testd);
    p.appendChild(texto);
  } else {
    p.innerHTML += ": " + testd;
  }
  
  p.style.color = "white";
  m.appendChild(p);
});
```

```css
#m {
  width: 300px:height:200px;
  background-color: rgba(21, 21, 21, 0.75)
}

.nombre-usuario {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.85);
}
```

```html
<div id="m">



</div>
```